# How to read data from one userspace app to another userspace process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, unix-sockets

From userspace application I read some data using IOCtl from kernel driver synchronously. Now Iam planning to move the driver to userspace. Is there a way for my userspace app to read some data from another userspace app synchronously

Comment: Try _Inter-Process Communication (IPC)_ (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) or [this](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc))

Comment: I am using unix domain sockets already ... but sometimes when source process send a packet to destination process I wanted to respond back from dest process if there are any errors in source packet and pass that data to src process. During that time how would I wait in source process? what is the best way to achieve this

Comment: sockets are _bi-directional_ ... in the source process, just read from the socket after writing to it to receive the response - the source process will block until the response arrives (unless you have set the socket to be _non-blocking_, in which case you will need to use _select()_ or _poll()_) ... alternatively, look at _[zeromq](https://zeromq.org/)_.